# Android Oreo(8.0) on back displays splash screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-8.0-oreo

I have observed this strange behavior with android 8.0 devices.

On app lunch shows splash screen as expected and moves to next activity(MainActivity). If i press back button in MainActivity it shows splash screen again for a moment and moves back to MainActivity by itself.

This happens only in Android 8.0 devices checked in Samsung S7 and Nexus 5X. 
Where as it worked without any issue in Android 5.0(Samsung J7).

Here i have added NoHistory = true in my splash activity as well in splash theme. 
Splash screen code similar to the one explained here: [xamarin android splash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen)

Things i tried:

- Adding oreo property(V26 style) android:windowSplashscreenContent instead of
  android:windowBackground in theme. [example link](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-splash-screen-for-api-26-and-below-7420d02904d1)
- Adding finish() in splash screen after navigation it works but shows some crash effect moreover i want    to know the reason for the above behavior.

Appreciated for any hints/root-cause for this issue. Thanks

**Edit:**
Code splash activity:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(SimulateStartup);
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    private async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate a bit of startup work. 
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        //Finish();
    }
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {

    }
}
```

Theme:

```
  <style name="InspectTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> 
<!--<item name="android:windowSplashscreenContent">@mipmap/ic_splash</item>-->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/ic_splash</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:noHistory">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Added device screen recording [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18tcC7DMHnHyVVy0cy_zKw4gTyJ_bZ6P7)

Sample code uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fJosMolojFatpvLueC5-YOkNAc1YPcE7)

Comment: First of all, you can override `OnBackPressed` method in MainActivity,  Prevent the back button like this code `public override void OnBackPressed() { }`, If it is still not work, could you provide a demo about your splash screen? I test https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen link, I can not reproduce this issue, it is running normally in Nexus 5X

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT expected behaviour when pressing back button is move app to background as usual, so cant disable it.   added splash screen code snippet. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT updated the sample code link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code in my device, this issue is related to

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` in `InspectTheme` of styles.xml.

If I delete this line, this GIF is running result.

[image]

There is styles.xml now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="InspectTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> 
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> 
 </style>


 <style name="InspectTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> 
<!--<item name="android:windowSplashscreenContent">@mipmap/ic_splash</item>-->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/ic_splash</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:noHistory">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```